# Read an object from Google Cloud Storage in Java

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform

I am using the Google Cloud Storage API ver 2.6.1, and all the examples in the SO/most Google searched websites/Google own sample codes, etc seem to be using either of the following two sequences :

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.newBuilder()
        .setProjectId(projectId)
        .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(newFileInputStream(serviceAccountJSON)))
        .build()
        .getService();
```

or, with the environment variable for access credentials defined,

```
Storage storage = StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance()
        .getService();
```

The problem is that the Class newbuilder() does not have neither .setProjectID, nor does getdefaultinstance() have a .getService().

My intent is to test if an object is present in a specific bucket, and if present download it to either memory or to a local file.

More updates : I went to the specifications given by @pringi and then located the guava-31.1-jre.jar, and installed it in the Project Structure. No joy.. the statement (and those following it) all show .cloud as red

```
import com.google.cloud.storage.Bucket;
```

Then I took the IntelliJ recommendation and had to install cloud code, which in turn installed another copy of google cloud SDK and created a whole new security key but I am still not able to get the 4 line example code work.

How do I go about doing this ?
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Are you using java or scala? If it is java then the correct version is 'com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:25.3.0'. See documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-java

Comment: @pringi I am using Java specifically Java 17. How do I download a jar of this com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:25.3.0 library ? Not using maven or gradle. The jar is not present in the maven repository.

Comment: Why do you need the project?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I do not need the project - but the requirement is what is specified in the variants 1 in all advisories. All I want is to download a file from cloud storage to the compute instance local disk.